# Spree Calculator - Amount Times Constant

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, spree

With my Spree 1-3-stable App I am using an extension called flexi_variant. With the extension it uses input fields to allow the user to add price altering descriptions.

I chose the standard calculator 'Amount Times Constant' and it almosts functions as expected; except instead of using the entire field as the obj to calculate an amount, it adds each letter.

This is what the caluclator looks like, and the suspected line. I've tried changing to count and other rewording but nothing seems to work. Any Ideas?

**_amount_times_constant.html.erb**

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
function calculate_amount_times_constant_price(obj) {
  return <%= calculator.preferred_multiplier %> * $(obj).val().length;
}
<% end %>
```

Comment: This appears to be a bug in flexi variants.  Can you file an issue on the project?

Comment: Hey gmacdougall, I added the issue in github. Thanks for the response. It's acting like what you would expect from the engraving calculator. Do you have any ideas of a quick fix?

Comment: btw gmacdougall, I am using stable-1-3 branch.

Comment: It does act like an engraving calculator.  The quick way to make it use a number entered instead would be to change $(obj).val().length to $(obj).val() (with a bit of validation when the value of not a number).  Even with that change, the math is still really wrong.  If something costs $10, and I want it to increase by 10% per addition, this will make it cost $11 (10 * 1.1 * 1) for the first, and $22 (10 * 1.1 * 2) for the second, which is probably not intended either...

Comment: Also gmacdougall, for some reason when I restart the rails app the first customization type will inherit the the 2nd. I only have 2. But when I first set them, it works as expexted. My first customization will stay at it's set 0, while the 2nd one will calculate the set cost. But the apps is restarted and I go to place an order, the first customization inherits what I had set for the 2nd... so.. Idk

Comment: I'm not sure about that one.  We only use the ad hoc options portion of flexi variants (which work pretty well), and not the customization types (which appear to have some issues).  You may need to pry it apart to see what's going on under the covers.

Comment: gmacdougall, I got it! All i did was erase .val() and not it just adds up the fields. instead of getting the value and length of letters. I still have the first one inherting the 2nd but so far still hope

Answer (score 0):

By changing this line

```
    return <%= calculator.preferred_multiplier %> * $(obj).val().length;
```

to

```
    return <%= calculator.preferred_multiplier %> * $(obj).length;
```

This calculates the entire field as a whole rather than each letter.